# Image contains errors after upload

Tags: python, image, upload, cgi

I'm trying to upload images with the following Python CGI function:

```
def save(image):
    path = '%s/%s' % ('dir/images', image.filename)
    nfile = open(path, 'wb')
    while 1:
        chunk = image.file.read(2<<16)
        if not chunk:
            break
        nfile.write(chunk)
    nfile.close()
```

It works fine with SVGs and text files, but when I try to upload an image (jpeg, png and gif tested), the resulting file cannot be displayed because it "contains errors". And it seems that the image is, indeed, not completely uploaded.
I really do not understand why it works with SVGs and TXTs, but not with images.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying my script on Debian, I found that my problem was definitely due to python for Windows, since it worked just fine on Debian.

To avoid getting truncated files when uploading binary files on Windows, you have to use the -u flag:

```
#! c:\python27\python.exe -u
```

And it should fix the truncated file problem.

http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2007-December/439231.html

Answer (score 3):

Umm, so anything that's below 131072 bytes probably works. But anything larger, has the first chunk written to the file, the file's then closed. So on the next iteration, the output file handle's closed, so can't be written to.

As @Lattyware has pointed out, this is an ideal time for using `with`: (and a few other bits)

```
path = os.path.join('dir', 'images', image.filename)
with open(path, 'wb') as fout:
    in_chunks = iter(lambda: image.file.read(2 << 16), '')
    fout.writelines(in_chunks)
```

Comment: +1, This is a good example of another reason to use the `with` statement to open files - it would make the error obvious here. (Plus it ensures the file is closed on exceptions).

Comment: Cheeky edit as there is a better way to construct the path too.

Comment: Thanks, forgot to check indentation on pasting, file is in fact closed at the end of the while. Trying your code right now!

Comment: Does not work either... Why everything is fine with other files?

Comment: @evuez wouldn't expect it to work if yours didn't - ummm, what's the filesize being uploaded and the filesize being saved? And is the content-type definitely set to `multipart/form-data` similar or something?

Comment: The filesize being uploaded is 35.8kb, and the filesize being saved is 2.8kb, so about 11/12 of the file is not saved. It is uploaded via a form with enctype="multipart/form-data".

Comment: What happens if you just do `fout.write(image.file.value)` ?

Comment: I get an internal server error: "malformed header from script. Bad header=   fout.write..."

Comment: @JonClements No server error, but image still "contains error" (while text and svg files are still fully uploaded).